# jquery dialog box: Get the dialog box ID while inside the dialog box

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

I have software that allows users to open several dialog boxes. Without going into a very long explanation of what I am doing, is it possible to pull the ID of the dialog box from within the dialog? So for example I might have a dialog box called 'dialog1' then another called 'dialog5', if I click on a link in the HTML of either on these dialog boxes (not clicking on the dialog box buttons), I need to know if its 'dialog1' or 'dialog5'.

As it stands I see two options:
1# Open the dialog box with a GET variable that holds the ID of the dialog box, then have PHP echo out its ID in places I need (and re-send that information in any ajax forms, then have that page return the data if the dialog is refresh, etc, etc, etc)....

2# Have each page with an HTML dom element with a specific id, then have JavaScript on load find that element, replace it with a randomly generated element(that way there wont be a conflict with new dialog boxes), then use the randomly generated element to traverse the DOM to dynamically pull the ID...

I tried both methods, and it seems method 2 is better, as it requires a lot less maintenance, but its an ugly solution (and would break if the DOM changes). Any better way to get this done?

Comment: when you are placing your links in  those dialog-boxes use html attr of link `data-dialog-id="#Dialog1"` and on click get this id.

Comment: In what way are the dialog boxes *called* 'dialog1' and 'dialog5'? Please post your code, or a simplified version of it.

Comment: franky: If I understand what you are saying, that seems more or less what I was doing with method 1.  ------------- Roamer-1888: Right now its 'dialog1' to 'dialog10', my code just looks for the first one that is not open, and uses it. But one day I will make this dynamic (so the user could open as many as they want).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bind an delegated click event to the outer wrapper in which all dialog ids exists.use common class for all dialogs("common-class").

```
<div class="outer-wrapper">
<div id="dialog-1" class="common-class" title="Basic dialog">
<p>This is the default dialog which is useful for displaying information. The dialog window can be moved, resized and closed with the 'x' icon.</p>
</div>
<div id="dialog-2" class="common-class" title="Basic dialog">
<p>This is the default dialog which is useful for displaying information. The dialog window can be moved, resized and closed with the 'x' icon.</p>
</div>
</div>

jQuery(".outer-wrapper").on("click",".common-class",function(){
   var dialogclick = jQuery(this).attr("id");
})
```

Comment: Not sure how that would work? How would a html within the dialog box trigger anything?

Comment: event is binded to output-wrapper,and child selector is specified as common-class so any thing clicked with in this will trigger click..

Comment: Can't seem to get it to work, not even your example in fiddle.Edit: Actually it does work in fiddle, hmm, ill take a closer look at this tomorrow.

Comment: Got it working, the problem was the $('').dialog was moving those divs outside of the 'outer-wrapper' div (making body its parent). Once I added 'outer-wrapper' as a class to the body, this seems to be working fine. I will tweak things in the morning, tnx.